# Calling SQLiteOpenHelper using a string passed in extra

Tags: java, android, sqliteopenhelper

I have two activities and multiple database classes and I want to pass the name of database class in the extras when going from Activity1 to Activity2 and load the DatabaseAdapter class in Activity2. Normally, I use

```
DatabaseAdapter databaseadapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
```

This works but not efficient.

1)Activity1 :It leads to Activity2. In the extras it'll pass "DatabaseAdapter" in string form.

2)In my second activity I want to use the methods of this DatabaseAdapter class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper class.

I tried using `Class<?> c = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass");`
But this throws unhandled exception:java.lang.class not found.

Answer (score 1):

your solution is incorrect, instead of pass class name to use that on another activity you can create new instance from `DatabaseAdapter` and use that, or you can create single instance from that and use every where which you want

Comment: The problem is I have a listview in Activity1. Which goes like Quiz1 Quiz2 Quiz3.... Clicking every element starts a Quiz(Activity2) and every Quiz has its Database.  I pass a string and use if condition in Activity 2 like this: if(string.equals("Quiz1")){  DatabaseAdapter1 databaseadapter = new DatabaseAdapter1(this); } if(string.equals("Quiz2")){  DatabaseAdapter2 databaseadapter = new DatabaseAdapter2(this); }and so on. It works but code gets very long.

Comment: @HasanSaykın instead of using database use table, for example tableQuiz1, tableQuiz2 and search on that on every activity which that passed from `putExtra` such as selected quiz

Comment: So, you are suggesting me to have one big database class filled with tables inside? But I want to keep my tables in separate classes(concerning performance and ease of editing.

Comment: For example I call database adapter 1 like this: DatabaseAdapter1 databaseadapter = new DatabaseAdapter1(this); and it Works in activity 2. But I want to like send a string like "DatabaseAdapter1" or "DatabaseAdapter2" from activity 1 to activity 2. And that class will be loaded in activity 2. Is this impossible?

Comment: @HasanSaykın its not big database, its not correct, i'm not sure its possible, you can use `DBFlow` on android, its simply library to use database on android